# How to generate key pair for php-jwt?

Tags: php, jwt

I am trying to use [PHP-JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to generate a JWT, but I always end up getting the error:

```
PHP Warning:  openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key
```

I have already tried generating the key pair with openssl, using opennssl protecting the key with a password then using `openssl_get_privatekey()` to read it, I've tried pasting the key in a multiline string in php (`EOT` and `EOD` delimiters). Then I tried copy/pasting the keys on the example page and still got the same error, what am I missing here?

Don't know if this could be a problem, but I am developing on a windows machine, then sending it to the remote server, which is a Linux machine...

EDIT:
How I generated the keys:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.pem 2048
```

reading with:

```
openssl_get_privatekey('keys/private.pem','0mrY2mX9NeAb0RmpcoeF');
openssl_get_privatekey('file://'.__DIR__.'/keys/private.pem','0mrY2mX9NeAb0RmpcoeF');
```

also tried:
    openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
reading with:

```
file_get_contents('keys/private.pem');
```

also tried with the in-line:

```
$private_key = <<<EOT
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOT;
```

But I don't think the problem is in how I am generating the keys, since the example on the README didn't work for me

Comment: Please add Your code to see how You try to generate them.

Comment: edited the question, but I don't think the problem is in how I am generating the keys, since the example on the README didn't work for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like You forgot to generate (or extract) public key from private key.

Please make sure You've done these steps:

1) generate private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
```

2) extract public key from private key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
```

3) and example php code:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$privateKey = file_get_contents('./private.pem');

$publicKey = file_get_contents('./public.pem');

$payload = [
  'data' => ['field1' => 1, 'field2' => 'string data'],
  "iss" => "http://example.org",
  "aud" => "http://example.com",
  "iat" => 1531498466,
  "eat" => 1557000000
];

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');
echo "Token:\n" . print_r($token, true) . "\n";


$decoded = JWT::decode($token, $publicKey, ['RS256']);
$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;

echo "Decoded:\n" . print_r($decoded_array, true) . "\n";
```

Bonus: **HS256 example**

Since HS256 is symmetric algorithm, it does not require private/public key pairs.

You may use Your own blablabla-like random secret string, without using generators and etc:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$secret = 'blablabla-secret-string'; 
// or You can save that random text in .jwt-secret  file and use this way
// $secret = file_get_contents('./.jwt-secret');

$payload = [
  'data' => ['field1' => 1, 'field2' => 'string data'],
  "iss" => "http://example.org",
  "aud" => "http://example.com",
  "iat" => 1531498466,
  "eat" => 1557000000
];

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $secret, 'HS256');
echo "HS256 Token:\n" . print_r($token, true) . "\n";


$decoded = JWT::decode($token, $secret, ['HS256']);
$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;

echo "HS256 Token decoded:\n" . print_r($decoded_array, true) . "\n";
```

Comment: @YuriWaki I'm glad that was helpful

Comment: @TheRealChx101 RS256 is an asymmetric algorithm, meaning it uses a public/private key pair.  HS256 is a symmetric algorithm, meaning there is one secret key shared, so it does not need key pairs. So You may use both of HS256 or RS256. But You've to decide what kind of security concept You prefer. For simplicity of implementation You can use HS256, it even does not need key RSA key generation, You can pass as secret whatever You want. For more info google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=jwt+rs256+vs+hs256&ie=utf-8

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I've added `Bonus` part with hs256 example.

Comment: Thanks. I was also doing my research while waiting for your answer and I did find out the HMAC/RSA are different. Also, you may want to warn users in case of unhandled exceptions/errors, your key might show up in the stack trace.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 `your key might show up in the stack trace` - my example with HS256 based use example: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#example but see, I've added example with dot-file (as `.jwt-secret`) that can be stored in server folder. But! If You think that someone can see that variable in stack trace - my answer is: `When app deployed to production, all stack traces, debug modes and etc must be disabled - it's common practice`.

Comment: Yes. It's common practice. But I'm using a library that I had no idea by default deploys in debug mode and has an error handler that prints function arguments/parameters and the author never pointed that out. It's something to look out for.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 as I wrote in example: `$secret = file_get_contents('./.jwt-secret');`  again, example is in github, is direct simplified example showing that it can be anything as secret for HS256. Also I'm using RS256 and have `.keys` folder which defined also in `.gitignore`. P.S. **You can keep secret string in  database**

Comment: @num8er Yes. I do get your point and it's exactly what I did in my project. *But*, what's happening is that, the error handler shows the actual contents of the key or whatever argument is passed to the offending function. So, it's something for anyone to look out for. It won't matter where the key is stored as once it gets in memory, and exception or script error is encountered, all related data will be exposed through the stack trace. BTW, the system is already suggesting we go to chat. So this will be my final comment.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 yes, that's possible to see it in backtrace - it's the way of debugging data (what if Your extra symbol in secret strign?). If You don't like to show that, You don't have to. Make some filter for backtrace to hide that sensitive data with `******` or You may disable debug, then use sentry (https://sentry.io/) and be alerted if something crashes with backtrace which is allowed to You.  See: http://joxi.ru/BA0aajsJyM6Dry  and http://joxi.ru/Rmzvv1u09YEBmO

Comment: Docs about sensitive data management in Sentry: https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/sensitive-data/